# How to add CORS through JS while opening tel:XXXXXXXXXX

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, mobile

I have a requirement to open native dialer through Java Script if we access from Android mobile. Since [ionincframework](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968/16) not allowing to open native dialer thourgh normal code, did some research and got to know that because of CORS it is not opening. Tried below code to apply CORS before using the tel:XXXXXXXXXXX protocol but not working.

```
<html>
<div class="phoneLinkDiv" onclick="javascript:createCORSRequest('POST','tel:555-999-8888');" data-rel="external">Hello</div>
<a href="tel:555-999-8888">Href</a> // Even this one also not working
<script>
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    alert("Inside with credentials");
    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    alert("Inside without credentials");
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;
    alert("Inside without credentials CORS not supported");

  }
  return xhr;
}


</script>
</html>
```

Suggest me any workaround for this or correct me if i am wrong. but same normal code working in chrome and safari.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

And then use:

```
<a href="tel:555-999-8888">Href</a>
```

Comment: Where we can have this config.xml. Typically in web J2EE project we have web.xml